# Access Value from ValuesQuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
obj_l = NewTable.objects.values('country').distinct();
```

when I print **obj_l** I get

```
[{'country':u'England'},{'country':u'USA'},{'country':u'Russia'}]
```

when I write **obj_l[0]** I get

```
{'country':u'England'}
```

what I just want the values of countries in array like

```
{England,USA,Russia}
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list) with `flat=True`:

```
obj_l = NewTable.objects.values_list('country', flat=True).distinct()
```